# Check Username or Password Availability Using AJAX on Codeigniter

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, codeigniter

Oke guys, i have some problem using AJAX to validate the availiblity of username, this is my code in codeigniter :

**VIEW**
a. The form

```
<input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="New Username" name="userId" id="userId" value="" onblur="return check_username();">
<div id="Info"></div></span><span id="Loading"><img src="<?php echo base_url(); ?>assets/img/loading.gif" alt="" /></span>
```

b. The Script

```
<script src="<?php echo base_url(); ?>assets/plugins/jquery-1.8.3.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
        $(document).ready(function() {
        $('#Loading').hide();    
            });

        function check_username(){

        var username = $("#userId").val();
            if(username.length > 2){
            $('#Loading').show();
            $.post("<?php echo base_url(); ?>admin/check_username_availablity", {
                username: $('#userId').val(),
                }, function(response){
            $('#Info').fadeOut();
            $('#Loading').hide();
        setTimeout("finishAjax('Info', '"+escape(response)+"')", 450);
            });
        return false;
        }
    }

function finishAjax(id, response){

  $('#'+id).html(unescape(response));
  $('#'+id).fadeIn(1000);
} 
</script>
```

**MODAL**

```
public function check_username_availablity(){
        $username = trim($this->input->post('userId'));
        $username = strtolower($username);  

        $query = $this->db->query("SELECT * FROM table_user WHERE userId='$username'");
        if($query->num_rows() > 0)
            return false;
        else
            return true;}
```

**CONTROLLERS**

```
public function check_username_availablity(){
      $this->load->model('m_admin');
      $get_result = $this->m_admin->check_username_availablity();

        if(!$get_result )
            echo '<span style="color:#f00">Username already in use. </span>';
        else
            echo '<span style="color:#00c">Username Available</span>';
    }
```

**The problem is in the form always shown that Username Available.**
Please help.. :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You passed `username` from jQuery with `username: $('#userId').val()` not `userId`

Try following with `$this->input->post('username')`

```
$username = strtolower(trim($this->input->post('username')));
```

Or change posted data index from jQuery: `username` to `userId`

```
userId: $('#userId').val()
```

Answer (score 0):

1: what happens when my username is "';DELETE FROM table_user;'" ? your query would become:

```
SELECT * FROM table_user WHERE userId = '';DELETE FROM table_user;''
```

So let's fix that: (And please: read the flipping manual)

```
$this->db->query('SELECT * FROM table_user WHERE userId = ?',array($username));
```

2: don't put business logic in your model:

```
function check_username_availability($username)
{
    // also the name of this function could better describe what it does:
    // is_username_available($username) for instance.
    // ...
}
```

3: What is the output of the query to select the user? What did you try to debug?

```
die(var_dump($this->db->last_query()));
```

4: You do realize you are checking a user **ID** against a user **NAME** right?